# Adding antenna gain to RX and TX sensitivity

Tags: rf, antenna

Let's say I have a transceiver with 10dBm of TX gain, and an RX sensitivity of -10dBm.   If I then attach an antenna with a gain of -2dBi do I then have an RF output power of 8dBm and an RX sensitivity of -8dBm?   I'm not clear on if I have to flip the sign when adding to the RX sensitivity but that would seem to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let's say I have an transceiver with 10dBm of TX gain

No, you mean it has a power output of 10 dBm. Gain has got nothing to do with power output capabilities.

> and an RX sensitivity of -10dBm

Yeah that's OK.

> If I then attach an antenna with a gain of -2dBi do I then have an RF
>   output power of 8dBm

Effectively, yes you do

> and an RX sensitivity of -8dBm

If the same antenna is at both ends of the link (or it's a transceiver using the antenna for RX and Tx) then yes.

> I'm not clear on if I have to flip the sign when adding to the RX
>   sensitivity but that would seem to make sense.

Yes it's a bit confusing but an antenna with -2 dB of gain compared to the (i)sotropic "standard" means you need 2 dB more power into your receiver's antenna because you have degraded the signal with the bad antenna.

And, because you have degraded the power output by 2 dB, your effective power out is 2 dB lower at 8 dBm

In practice, an antenna with loss compared to an isotropic antenna is a pretty crappy antenna and a receiver with a sensitivity of only -10 dBm is also pretty crappy.

Comment: "an antenna with loss compared to an isotropic antenna is a pretty crappy antenna" - eh, not necessarily. Most electrically small antennas have < 0 dBi of gain, sometimes as low as -25 dBi for really small devices. By sacrificing gain you can make some really tiny wireless gadgets.

Comment: @PeterK and of course you are right!